# Axios.post on the front end doesn't return ant result

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, react-router

The idea of this app is that the user types the Twitter account id (say 'nodejs') on the website home page's search bar and uses axios.post it to the server. The Express app uses that string to pull data from Twitter API.

I can get the API results shown on the console that runs Express but I can't get the results back to the client. It simply just returns nothing. For the website URL, it is supposed to be localhost:3000/dashboard/nodejs, but it ends up with localhost:3000/?search=nodejs (The name for input element is 'search'). And the website just won't switch and stays on the home page.

fetchTweets(client):

```
const fetchTweets = (value, postBody) => {
    console.log('fetched from frontend')
    return (
        axios.post(`/${value}`, postBody)
            .then(res => {
                const result = res.data;
                return { result }
            })
    )
}
```

handleSubmit(calls fetchTweets):

```
const handleSubmit = async (value) => {
        try {
            const postBody = { twitterId: '0' }
            const res = await fetchTweets(value, postBody);
            console.log(res)
            if (res.result.usernameError) {
                setError('No username found. Please enter a correct username')
                console.log(error)
            }
            else if (res.result.serverError) {
                setError('Error Fetching Data from Server')
                console.log(error)
            }
            else {
                setTweets(res.result)
                history.push({
                    pathname: `/dashboard/${value}`,
                })
            }
        } catch {
            setError('Error fetching data from server.')
        }
    }
```

Search component:

```
<Search 
    onSubmit={async (value) => {
        setError(false);
        setLoading(true);
        handleSubmit(value)
}} />
```

router(server):

```
router.post('/:account', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    lastTwitterId = req.body.twitterId;
    twitterObject = await twitter.getTweets(req.params.account.toLowerCase(), lastTwitterId);
    res.status(200).json(twitterObject)
    res.status(200).end();
  } catch {
    res.status(501).json({ serverError: true })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `fetchTweets()` isn't awaiting the axios request. It's returning nothing because the request is still in progress when you return.

Also, `try-catch` is prefered instead of `.then().catch()`.

Example:

```
const fetchTweets = (value, postBody) => {
    console.log('fetched from frontend');
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`/${value}`, postBody);
        return response.data;
    } catch(err) {
        return err.message;
    }
}
```